# Bluetooth Client-Server Example in Android

Tags: java, android, bluetooth, client-server

I am making a simple client-server application which can be used to transfer integers, strings or characters.

My application compiled successfully, but no client-server connection is there.
When I try to search for a server, it gives the NullPointerException on the line

```
bluetooth.startDiscovery();
```

However, when I start the server it gives no exception.

Also, when I start a server on one device and look for a server on another, a connection is not established either due to a problem in server running correctly or a problem in the client.

I have already got an instance of BluetoothAdapter using

```
bluetooth = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
```

I think that probably a null pointer is given because i am calling the method startDiscovery() inside an onclickListener, this one,

```
private void setupSearchButton() {
    Button searchButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_search);
    searchButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View view) {
            registerReceiver(discoveryResult, new IntentFilter(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND));
            if (!bluetooth.isDiscovering()) {
              try {  foundDevices.clear();
                bluetooth.startDiscovery(); } catch(Exception e)
                {
                Context c = getApplicationContext();
                    Toast.makeText(c, e.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                }
            }
        }
    });
}
```

The code for declaring a server is posted here :

```
    @Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == DISCOVERY_REQUEST) {
        boolean isDiscoverable = resultCode > 0;
        if (isDiscoverable) {
            String name = "bluetoothserver";
            try {
                final BluetoothServerSocket btserver = bluetooth.listenUsingRfcommWithServiceRecord(name, uuid);
                AsyncTask<Integer, Void, BluetoothSocket> acceptThread = new AsyncTask<Integer, Void, BluetoothSocket>() {

                    @Override
                    protected BluetoothSocket doInBackground(Integer... params) {

                        try {
                            socket = btserver.accept(params[0] * 1000);
                            return socket;
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            Log.d("BLUETOOTH SERVER EXCEPTION : ", e.getMessage());
                        }

                        return null;
                    }

                    @Override
                    protected void onPostExecute(BluetoothSocket result) {
                        if (result != null) {
                            switchUI();
                        }
                    }
                };
                acceptThread.execute(resultCode);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.d("BLUETOOTH", e.getMessage());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Can someone tell me what is the problem ? I am using two buttons, one to start a bluetooth server and other to search for a bluetooth server. The method that runs on clicking the start bluetooth server button triggers startActivityForResult, as a result of which the method onActivityResult is executed as shown here. The OnClickListener for search server button is already shown here.

Comment: Are you using bluetooth permissions in your `AndroidManifest.xml`?

Comment: yes. and both BLUETOOTH and BLUETOOTH_ADMIN